# Android Retrofit/OkHttp Use `8.8.8.8` programatically for DNS lookup?

Tags: android, dns, retrofit, okhttp

I am trying to add Google DNS lookup which is '8.8.8.8.' in my android app, I am using Retrofit with OkHttp.

Is it possible programmatically?

I saw this post but wasn't able to add it [dns-android-okhttp](https://garage.easytaxi.com/tag/dns-android-okhttp/).

Comment: Could you expand on why you couldn't get dnsjava working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working now actually in the [dns-android-okhttp](https://garage.easytaxi.com/tag/dns-android-okhttp/) I was searching, I was looking for which library he is using for Resolver which was `dnsjava`

> compile 'dnsjava:dnsjava:2.1.7'

And now after adding it, my code is working correctly.

Comment: How did you call EasyDns class?

Comment: @FaxriddinAbdullayev I am using okhttp as interceptor so I called it by `new OkHttpClient.Builder().dns(new EasyDns())`, where `EasyDns` is the class implementing `Dns`, see here in the link https://garage.easytaxi.com/tag/dns-android-okhttp/

Answer (score 5):

If you want to try DNS over HTTPS querying Google (not technically 8.8.8.8) then it's supported as an experimental module within OkHttp

```
OkHttpClient bootstrapClient = new OkHttpClient();

Dns google = new DnsOverHttps.Builder().client(bootstrapClient)
    .url(HttpUrl.get("https://dns.google.com/experimental"))
    .build();
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().dns(google).build();

Response result =
    client.newCall(new Request.Builder().url("https://google.com/robots.txt").build())
        .execute();

System.out.println(result.body().string());
```

Comment: hey I found the solution, the library was `dnsjava`, after adding it everything is working perfectly fine, thanks anyways for helping :)

Comment: Which library are you using? `DnsOverHttps`? Thanks

Comment: I tried already with OkHttp 3.14 and the most recent and I am still unable to reach this module.

Comment: 3.14 isn't a supported version, if you upgrade to recent versions it is available https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-dnsoverhttps

So 4.8.1.

Comment: How do I test that DNS works? I mean, how do I get actuall DNS (receiving in this case 8.8.8.8)? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but awkward to opt into Google 8.8.8.8 regular DNS, you need to write your own DNS implementation using a library like Netty or dnsjava.  Here's one I just whipped up.

e.g. https://github.com/yschimke/okurl/blob/release/1.57/src/main/kotlin/com/baulsupp/okurl/network/NettyDns.kt